# Embedding A Googlemap via PHP include statement

Tags: php, google-maps, php-include

I have created a custom google map to display my business branches, (which is stored in a file called [map-locations].php.

When i open this file in a browser the file displays perfectly, however if i try to include this php file using an include statement  it does not display at all.

I have tried to copy and paste the code directly into the page on my website i would like the code to show, but it does not show there either.

I would much rather be able to have the map displaying via an include statement, but right now just to display at all would be great!

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      .wrap { max-width: 75em; min-height: 40em; height:600px; width:500px;   margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 2.5%;}
      #map-canvas { height: 90%; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var centerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(51.6491587,0.0386048);
      var zoomLevel = 11;


      function LogoControl(controlDiv, map) { 
  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://www.1stopinstruction.com/media/images/logos/1stop/googlemap-title.gif)';
  controlUI.style.width = '275px';
  controlUI.style.height = '65px';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(centerPos)
    map.setZoom(zoomLevel)
  });

}

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: centerPos,
          zoom: zoomLevel
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions );
            var locations = [
  ['East London - Ilford (Fairlop Powerleague)', 51.598589, 0.101594],
  ['North London - Tottenham (Frederick Knight Sports Ground)',51.607052, -0.054270],
  ['Highams Park - Chingford (LGV & PCV Only)',51.609685, -0.005183],
  ['North Weald Airfield (kneedown & Wheelie Only)',51.717709, 0.160214],
  ['Office Address',51.572126, 0.106147]
]
var image = "http://www.1stopinstruction.com/media/images/logos/1stop/googlemap-icon.gif";

 logoControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var logoControl = new LogoControl(logoControlDiv, map);

logoControlDiv.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(logoControlDiv);


for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    title: locations[i][0],
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
}
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

  <body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: using jQuery is an option?

Comment: Have you checked your HTML at your browser level to see if the map <div> is even created? If its not there your problem is the include. If it is there the problem is whats inside the include.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your javascrip code is executed before the DOM is completely charged. Put your javascript code at the botton of the document after the `<div class="wrap">...</div>` but inside the `body` tag